# Адаптивное меню по центру экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdmr8vm1/9/)

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы меню всегда располагалось строго по центру экрана
независимо от его разрешения, как это реализовать в моём случае?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.activatemenu').click(function() {
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("position", "absolute");
    $('.topmenu').animate({
      height: "200%"
    }, 500);
    $('.deactivatemenu').animate({
      top: "5%"
    }, 500);
    $('.activatemenu').fadeOut(250);
    $('.deactivatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
  });
  $('.deactivatemenu').click(function() {
    $('.topmenu').animate({
      height: "3rem"
    }, 500);
    $('.activatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.deactivatemenu').fadeOut(250);
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");
    $("html,body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
    $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
    $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

 :active,
 :hover,
 :focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p {
  cursor: default;
}

.mobiletext {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.mobilemenu {
  display: block;
  color: #e6e6e6 !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  text-align: center;
}


.deactivatemenu {
display: none;
}

.topmenu {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 3rem;
background: #000;
opacity: 1;
z-index: auto;
}

.fa-times, .fa-bars {
text-decoration: none;
color: #e6e6e6;
position: relative;
font-size: 1.5em;
z-index: 5;
}

.topvk {
  color: #e1e1e1 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  font-size: 1.650em;
}

.iconmargin {
margin-top: 20%;
padding-left: 5%;
  margin-left: 8%;
}

.content {
  font-family: 'Roboto:100', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
    <div class="deactivatemenu">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      <p class="mobiletext">Close</p>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="#1" class="mobilemenu">Home</a>
        <a href="#2" class="mobilemenu">About me</a>
        <a href="#3" class="mobilemenu">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#4" class="mobilemenu">Comments</a>
        <a href="#5" class="mobilemenu">Contact</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk faicon iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter faicon iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook faicon iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="activatemenu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <p class="mobiletext">Menu</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1 class="content">Site content</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант... [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdmr8vm1/11/)

```
.deactivatemenu {
  display: none;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я у себя сделал так:

```
<div class="spinner-container" style="display:none;"></div>

.spinner-container {
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-color: #bfaeae;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Див spinner-container когда нужно отображается по центру экрана, поверх всего остального.
Возьмите из стиля для себя, что нужно...